# HTML Table nesting | Alignment - 2 x <td> on the same line

Tags: html

Hope you can help me with this its probably really simple but I'm pretty bad at nesting.

Here is the simple code:

```
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">

        <tr>
            <td width="600"><a href="#" target="_blank"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center" bgcolor="#000000" colspan="2"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" width="9" height="11" border="0" alt="" style="display:block;"></a><font style="font-size: 12px" color="#ffffff" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans serif"><b><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff">LEAVE A REVIEW TO <font color="#ff9a11">WIN &pound;250</font> WORTH OF X VOUCHERS</a></b></font></td>

        </tr>

        </table>
```

If you pop that into an editor or open in a browser all I'm trying to do is  sit the two data cells on the same line, you'll notice there's an image with no image that's 9x11px that is an image of a bullet point, that should give you the idea of what I wanna do. However I try everything goes mental.

If you could explain why that's happening that would be awesome because I'm learning HTML for email (being in emailing for my job)

Comment: Advice. Don't use the font tag. Use a span tag and apply a style to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the style -  display: block from the bullet image. That style makes the image live in its own `line`.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">

        <tr>
            <td width="600"><a href="#" target="_blank"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center" bgcolor="#000000" colspan="2"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" width="9" height="11" border="0" alt=""></a><font style="font-size: 12px" color="#ffffff" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans serif"><b><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff">LEAVE A REVIEW TO <font color="#ff9a11">WIN &pound;250</font> WORTH OF X VOUCHERS</a></b></font></td>

        </tr>

        </table>
```

Comment: Thanks that does it and it make sense, nice one!

Comment: Dont forget to mark answers as correct. People with low acceptance scores tend to get ignored in future questions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1 of Row 1 </td>
        <td>Column 2 of Row 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Only column in Row 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Your issue was that you had a `<td>` with a `colspan` of 2 when there weren't two columns to span. Your other two columns were seperated into two seperate rows, which I adjusted for you in that code.

edit: I've cleaned up to table code to it's barebones so you can understand it easier

Comment: You should state what you did to fix it. The OP asked why it was happening.

Comment: This does not fix the problem. The bullet point is still on another line.